# Assigning sensor information to image coordinates

Tags: android, navigation, android-sensors, indoor-positioning-system, pedometer

I'm developing an indoor navigation application. I want to move the arrow sign in the field with the information I obtain from the device's sensor. If we think of the area as a room, as you move around the room with the phone, the arrow sign will move towards the same place in the area.

[image]

At this stage, I can get pitch, tilt, azimuth values and detect whether a step has been taken.

What can I do to make the arrow mark reach the red dot?

I assigned the azimuth value to the arrow image.

```
float angle = (float) azimuth * -1;
imgMarker.setRotation(angle);
```

I try to change the position of the picture as I take each step.

```
if (imgMarker.getRotation() > 0) {
                        imgMarker.setPadding(imgMarker.getPaddingLeft(), imgMarker.getPaddingTop(), imgMarker.getPaddingRight() + 10,stepCount * 10);
                    } else {
                        imgMarker.setPadding(imgMarker.getPaddingLeft() + 10, imgMarker.getPaddingTop(), imgMarker.getPaddingRight(),stepCount * 10);
                    }
```

Comment: How accurate do you need to be?  Is this a specific room, or any generic room?  If it's a specific room, use bluetooth beacons to triangulate a location.  It can get you to sub meter accuracy.  If it's a generic room-  you're kind of guessing.  GPS isn't accurate enough indoors.  You can guess how big a step is, and use your angle to go from there.  If it's actually outside-  use GPS.

Comment: It will be a room of certain dimensions. There will be some objects in certain locations in the room. My goal is to direct the user to those objects.

Comment: Bluetooth beacons hidden in the room to triangulate locations is probably the right answer, and fairly cheap.  There's off the shelf solutions you can use for under $100.  The idea is that you put the beacons at known locations, and based on how strong their signal is you know how far away you are.  If you have multiple beacons, you can figure out your exact location relative to the beacons based off how far you are from each and triangulating.  Then there's no need for messing with the sensors at all.

Comment: Wow. This option is very valuable for the future. However, at this stage I need to do it with sensors. I expect support from those who have knowledge on this subject.